# SQL Server 2008 Queued Transactional Replication vs Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

In SQL Server 2008 R2. What's the difference between queued transactional replication vs merge replication?. I undestand that in both cases the servers not to be on line (my case). So can i choose any of them?

Answer (score 5):

From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

> Replication scenarios can be divided into two broad categories: replicating data in a server to server environment and replicating data between server and clients. The server to server scenarios are implemented using transactional replication (and sometimes snapshot replication); the server and client scenarios are implemented using merge replication.

Transactional Replication:

> Transactional replication is typically used in server-to-server environments and is appropriate in each of the following cases:

- You want incremental changes to be propagated to Subscribers as they
  occur. The application requires low latency between the time changes
  are made at the Publisher and the changes arrive at the Subscriber.
- The application requires access to intermediate data states. For
  example, if a row changes five times, transactional replication
  allows an application to respond to each change (such as firing a
  trigger), not simply the net data change to the row.
- The Publisher has a very high volume of insert, update, and delete
  activity.
- The Publisher or Subscriber is a non-SQL Server database, such as
  Oracle.

Merge Replication:

> Merge replication is typically used in server-to-client environments. Merge replication is appropriate in any of the following situations:

- Multiple Subscribers might update the same data at various times and
  propagate those changes to the Publisher and to other Subscribers.
- Subscribers need to receive data, make changes offline, and later
  synchronize changes with the Publisher and other Subscribers.
- Each Subscriber requires a different partition of data.
- Conflicts might occur and, when they do, you need the ability to
  detect and resolve them.
- The application requires net data change rather than access to
  intermediate data states. For example, if a row changes five times at
  a Subscriber before it synchronizes with a Publisher, the row changes
  only once at the Publisher to reflect the net data change (that is,
  the fifth value).